# EXC_BAD_ACCESS & EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION errors in grouped table view

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone apps development. I am trying to develop a small app consisting of table views . when i am in a grouped table view and trying to do something(scrolling or entering values in textfields in the table cell) i get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS or EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors..

Pls can anybody suggest me a solution for this...

Comment: You are probably accessing an object that you have already released. You can try enabling `NSZombies` and check the console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug and see the point where it is crashing and see to it you haven't released the object which you're not allowed to do.